# How to make two API calls such that if one fails all of them fails in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am making two api calls in my angular code (1st api is POST and 2nd is PUT) and i want to make sure either both of them successfully executes or none of them.

**Scenarios :**

1. Meaning if the first 1st api call fails, call to 2nd api should not be made and should show the error for the first 1st api only.
2. IMPORTANT CASE : If the 1st api executes successfully and 2nd api fails, the 1st api call that was made should be rejected and i should show error for 2nd api (or to say none of them should get called)

```
//Just a example call for api
this.movementService.saveMovementDetails(movData).subsribe()
this.tourService.saveTourDetails(tourId,tourData).subsribe()
```

So far i have tried mergemap, forkJoin in RxJS but i am not able to figure out how will I be able to achieve this. Any help will mean a lot to me!

Comment: I don't think you can achieve your goal. Once "1st api executes successfully" there is no automatic way to roll it back if the second fails. Even if the back end offers you a `rollback` function, you still are not sure that the roll back will work. If the 2 apis are offered by the same back end system, you may ask the backend to implement a new service that packs the 2 operations and that, potentially, may control the transaction. But if the 2 apis are served by different systems, the control of the transaction is much more difficult and definitely can not be done by the client on the browser.

Comment: The only way to code your first scenario is to do the API calls in serial, not parallel. Unless you have a time machine and can go back in time to stop the second call from being made at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a really hard problem. it's a distributed transaction which can be really difficult to solve. I would recommend not doing it in the client. You really can't trust a browser to handle this. You won't be able to just cancel the api call either, you will need to make an additional api call to rollback the api call that succeeded. I would highly suggest trying to make this into one api call/transaction if it's possible.

If for some reason you can't make it one api call and one transaction, I would suggest moving this logic onto the server and using the saga pattern where each step in the process can be rolled back if a step later in the process fails. You can learn more about it [here](https://medium.com/design-microservices-architecture-with-patterns/saga-pattern-for-microservices-distributed-transactions-7e95d0613345)

[image: saga pattern]

Comment: thanks for the explanation, instead of doing this by creating only one api can we do it using apache kafka?? Have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I only have theoretical knowledge of kafka, but whoever suggested it must have a good idea of how they want it done.

Answer (score 0):

You must call one Api inside another. for example:

```
this.movementService.saveMovementDetails(movData).subsribe(
result => console.log(result)
//your code
    this.tourService.saveTourDetails(tourId,tourData).subsribe(
    result2 => console.log(result2)
       error => {
       //set result to null
     }
    )

   error => {
   this.errors = error
 }
)
```

if first api is failed second api not called and if the second api fails can set result of first api to null.

Comment: I think this is wrong, since it does not rollback the first api if the second fails, and also not rxjs idiomatic, since `subscribe`s within `subscribe`s are not considered good rxjs style.

Comment: if the second fails can set result to null

Comment: @Picci will try but then we have to call another delete api for the rollback

Comment: @blume0F right, you have to call a `delete` api to rollback. However the problem remains. What happens if `delete` fails?

Comment: @Picci ahaha its a deadlock

Comment: It is a bad practice in rxjs to have a subscription inside another subscription. Please refer to this article https://www.thinktecture.com/en/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/

Comment: Read the question first. This answer is according to the question. If you have a better answer, tell me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem exactly then actually you want that either both calls should be succeeded or neither of them, for this if your API calls is neither dependent on each other data then use Promis.all function. This return promise when all of the input's promises have fulfilled or it rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error. You should Promise.all documentation. Hope this will help in solving your problem.

Comment: ok i will try with this one. isn’t promise.all and forkjoin the same?

Comment: `promise.all` is similar to `forkjoin`. The problem of how to delete the effects of one api if the other fails reamai s.

Comment: @Picci would you like to explain this line 'The problem of how to delete the effects of one api if the other fails reamai' sorry I am unable to understand

Comment: 'The problem of how to delete the effects of one api if the other fails‘ remains. In other words, you do not solve it with `promise.all` or `forkjoin`.